# Integration tests for custom pallets

Tags: pallet, testing

There is a very nice and structured way of writing unit test against a pallet. One can find  a lot of examples of unit tests as well.

I will be thankful if any one can point me to some resources/samples of integration tests against pallets please.

Comment: What kind of integration tests? Multiple pallets within Rust code? Or spinning up a node and connecting to it?

Comment: My question is about multiple pallets within rust code. 1. Any example/ samples of integration tests in this cases 2. Any guideline/ industry standard in case of  substrate pallets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/paritytech/parachains-integration-tests has tests that are geared up to XCM integration testing, and I hear that https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet also can run integration tests itself. There are also a few good recent talks at sub0 that are relevant: [How to sleep at night](https://youtu.be/a_u3KMG-n-I) and [Centrifuge: FUDGE - Integration Tests for Substrate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-hAMK6ySXU&list=PLOyWqupZ-WGvywLqJDsMIYdCn8QEa2ShQ&index=4) and [Acala's chopsticks framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJqbO45DVIA).