# Automating Sync Tests for a Substrate Node: Best Approaches?

Tags: testing, cicd

I am working on a Substrate node that needs to **sync with specific live networks**. My goal is to ensure that the node is able to initiate and maintain synchronization with these networks, and I would like to **integrate this testing into my continuous integration (CI) pipeline**.

I'm looking for a convenient and **scalable strategy** that can be extended with other test cases in the future. Here's what I have in mind so far:

1. **Environment Setup**: Should I connect directly to the live network, or is it better to replicate the conditions in a controlled environment?
2. **Node Launch and Configuration**: How can I automate the launch of the node with the correct parameters for each network?
3. **Monitoring and Verification**: What tools or scripts are recommended to monitor the synchronization process and verify success? Is there any existing solution that could simplify this task?
4. **Integration with CI**: What are the best practices for integrating this testing into a CI pipeline to ensure consistent verification?
5. **Extensibility**: How can I structure these tests so that they can be easily extended with additional cases or adapted to other networks in the future?

I appreciate any insights, examples, or references that can guide me in developing an efficient and robust testing strategy. Thank you!

Comment: Hey I thought this answer may be helpful:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6607/2909